# Holding down the power button on a PC while disconnected from power

Tags: repair

Many times I would call tech support, and they would say turn off the laptop (take out the battery, hold down the power button, and try turning it back on.  I have always wondered what purpose this serves.  I recently read a article specifying for mac computers that this resets the SMC. Does doing this with a windows PC have the same effect?  Is there a SMC inside all computers? What effect does this action have on non mac pcs? Is it the same for desktops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It drains all residual power from the motherboard and memory modules, what that actually resets depends on the design of the motherboard.

[As Gateway explains it](http://support.gateway.com/s/Checklists/BPC/ck2007050376.shtml):

> The process drains stored electrical energy in some critical circuits on the motherboard. These circuits start the computer properly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if its universal but its also true of [thinkpads](http://www.masnick.com/2007/09/07/the-secret-thinkpad-powerbutton-code-to-bring-dead-laptops-back-to-life/), and some other systems (according to the comments and this [post](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/60038-35-dv9000-static-build-hold-power-button-secs) about HPs ) and [apparently even tablets](http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/402-wont-power-ono/).

Reasons range from ACPI resets, to static removal, to MAGIC. Its worth trying out, but dosen't always work in my experience

Comment: also on some android tablet type items it slamms them off when hung.  On Desktop PCs depending on how the Setting in windows and bios , the Off switch performs 2 functions, Quick press , is proper shut-down, Longer than 4 second press is SLAM the PSU into off state. really bad thing to do when running.  Then when having Bios issues usually when overclocking, Slamming the power off , can drop the bios back into "being able to post" by temporarily setting default/standard bios settings.  It doesnt reset the saved bios. It also depends on the Bios/motherboard

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but doesn't static destroy ICs, can it actually just render them temporarily useless?

Comment: Honestly? The static explaination sounds almost as bad as the MAGIC explainations. ACPI resets are the least j00j00 explaination i have heard.